# How to install .NET 3.0 or 3.5 on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows, .net, installation, windows-server-2003

I'm having difficulty installing .NET 3.0 or 3.5 on my Virtual Dedicated Server with Windows Server 2003. I get this error every time: http://img402.imageshack.us/i/net30setuperror.jpg/

Any suggestions about how I can get this installation to succeed?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you downloaded the correct version? There might be a specific version meant for server and the version you are trying to install is XP. Also 32bit vs 64bit might make a difference.

Maybe you need the full package? http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe

Or scroll down to the bottom of the following website for some command line switches to try... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262841